# Identify the opposite value in the same column and update the another column - Uipath linq

Tags: uipath, uipath-activity

[image]

The credit and debit values have to be tallied.
For example, cell C4 has -1 as value. We need to look for +1 value in column C where column D value should not be Credit or Debit. Once we find that, the value in column D should be changed to Debit.

Here, in this case, C4 will have to find C3 and change value of D3 to Debit.

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you created any code yet if so what does it do? And can you update your question with what you have already tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So far I have completed filter DT based on the customer id and try to identify the same opp value is there are not in the column.